# Error during inserting data from SQL Server to DB2

Tags: ssis, db2, ssis-2016

I have made a simple DataFlow task in SSIS to move data rfom SQL Server to DB2 on AS400. The connection is OK. I'm able to view and map the columns. The package compiled find. However, I'm getting below run time message.That is just after the "[SSIS.Pipeline] Information: Execute phase is beginning."

> [OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft DB2 OLE DB Provider"  Hresult: 0x80040E37  Description: "SYSCOLUMNS?TABLE in OPERA type *N not found. SQLSTATE: 42704, SQLCODE: -204".
>
> [OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred,
>    and the error row disposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.
>   The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (15). 
>   The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [OLE DB Source [115]] Error: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on OLE DB Source returned error code 0xC02020C4.
>   The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). 
>   The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Could anyone please tell me whats going wrong? How to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Db2 on i-series  rejected the query that came from SSIS, maybe because column qsys2.syscolumns.table does not exist .   What has changed recently?

Comment: See also the description of the -204 "type *N not found" at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1019720